# What will happen to a compressible fluid filled inside a sealed container when the container begins to accelerate?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, air

Assume the fluid to be air and the container to be a car, will there be a pressure gradient which will result the fluid to stack at one end of the car or there is something else that I'm missing?

Comment: You aren't missing anything and you're quite correct. The acceleration will make the pressure higher at the rear end of the car just as the acceleration due to Earth's gravity makes the air pressure higher nearer the ground.

Comment: Thanks John. But sumthing's stil hazy in my mind, while the acceleration due to gravity varies with altitude and typically has fixed value for a particular altitude in time, in our case the value of acceleration varies from 0 to some positive value in time. I was trying to verify my reasoning if the entire mass of air inside the car experience the same acceleration as that of car and it is due to it's ability to resist the change that results in air getting compressed at the end of the car. So it would be of great help if you could help me connect the dots in your analogy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variation on the semi-well-known helium balloon experiment.  Sit in a car while holding a He balloon so it floats freely.  Accelerate hard & observe which way the balloon moves.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a continuation of my comment, but it got a bit long for a comment.

As I mentioned in my original comment, if the acceleration is constant then we get a static pressure gradient just like we get a pressure gradient in the atmosphere. Incidentally, the Earth's gravitational field is approximately constant up to say the stratopause, so it's a good model for an evenly accelerating car.

If the acceleration changes with time then we get an interesting phenomenon i.e. we get pressure waves or, as they sometimes called, sound waves. To see this assume that your car accelerates then brakes in a sinusoidal fashion, $a = a_0 \sin(\omega t)$. Then the ends of the cylinder of air behave just like two loudspeakers facing each other.

[image: Air]

If you accelerate the cones of the loudpeakers in the same way as you accelerate the ends of your box of air in the car then the air between them will behave in the same way. And as we know, speakers produce sound waves. Obviously we normally think of speakers as changing their accelerating at high frequencies like a kilohertz while a car acceleration changes with frequencies in the sub 1Hz range, but the principle is the same.